# On the working of radios and interference of waves driving radios and TVs?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-current

It's a well known fact that radios work by ensuring that the resonant frequency of their LCR circuits matches the frequency of the station one is trying to tune into, however, waves also interfere, so how is the radio able to separate or decompose these waves to match the frequencies.

Note:- I don't know much about EM waves, so I'm assuming they behave similarly to sound waves

Comment: Sometimes radio reception is impacted by waves interfering. But this is a really broad question. You might want to start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation (and associated amplitude modulation) to get an idea of just how 'tuning' works. (And software defined radio uses no resonant circuits but rather math manipulations to decode AM/FM/...)

Comment: Re, "waves also interfere..." I am not able to answer how a resonator is unaffected by waves of the wrong frequency, but I think that "interference" maybe does not mean what you think it means. When physicists talk about wave interference, they usually are talking about something that happens between two or more sources of waves that have _exactly the same frequency._ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference

Comment: so don't wave with different frequencies affect one another?

Comment: waves do interfere so that "5+3 = 8" but if  you know that the "3" was interfered with a "5" to form "8" and you measured "8" then by subtraction you also know that the underlying signal is "3".

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: so essentially by measuring waves that combined with one another and some that didn't radios  are able to decide which wave was which. right?

Comment: Find a still pond and two small stones. Plonk the stones into the pond near to each other. Watch the expanding rings of ripples. The ripples are waves. Notice how the two expanding rings pass right through each other—unaffected by each other. That's how waves interact in a linear medium: They obey the [_superposition principle_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). Superposition explains both why waves pass through each other without affecting each other, and it also explains why, when you look at the place where waves _with exactly the same frequency_ are passing...

Comment: ...through each other, you may seen an [_interference pattern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_interference).

Comment: @hyportnex, A radio does not tune in the station that you want to listen to by "subtracting out" the signals from all of the other radio stations on the dial. It has no way of knowing what to subtract. A radio's tuner is a [_resonant circuit_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonator) that only responds to excitations (i.e., radio waves) of one particular frequency. Like I said in my first comment above, I am not qualified to give a mathematical explanation of why the tuner does _not_ respond to all of the other "wrong" signals that are present at the same time.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot @SolomonSlow

Comment: @SolomonSlow the "thing" that does this is called a "filter", and it is called a filter because it removes (subtracts, yes indeed it subtracts) the unwanted parts of the spectrum; there are even filters that remove signals falling in the same frequency band as the desired signal and if properly designed they are called "matched filters", (That is not the definition of a matched filter but its practice...) There are even such, without getting into the nitty-gritty, that are placed right after the antenna or even made part of it.

Comment: @hyportnex, Yes, what comes out of a filter is the sum of all of the signals at the input, minus the undesired signals. But fhhh's comment above implies that the only way to obtain that one desirable, but unknown signal is to _mathematically_ subtract out all of the _known_ undesirable signals. I don't have enough math background to explain what the IF stage of a radio actually does, but I know that it does _not_ literally work by subtracting known signals from the unknown even if the outcome is the same as if it did work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number of reasons information (radio and television signals) is added to a *carrier* electromagnetic wave produced by a transmitter by a process called modulation.   Perhaps the simplest method is just to switch the carrier wave on and off for certain time periods which relate to sending dots (carrier on for a short time interval) and dashes   (carrier on for a longer time interval) so the information is transmitted as Morse code.

The range of carrier frequencies is enormous, magahertz to gigahertz, and each transmitter sends signals at a particular carrier frequency.

An important idea is that the multitude of carrier waves produced by numerous transmitters overlap with one another (superpose) but whilst overlapping the individual carrier waves do not change their frequency or the information they carry.  So the word *interference* which is used when describing the overlap of waves in this context is a historical misnomer as the process of overlap does not change the nature of the waves, ie they do not *interfere* with one another, once the waves have passed through one another they have undergone no change.

A receiver is designed to select a particular carrier wave frequency (eg using a LCR tuned circuit)  in preference to all the other carrier wave frequencies which are around and then extract the information  (radio and television signals) as appropriate.

Interference in the non technical/scientific sense, the degrading of the information, can take a number of forms.  For example: two transmitter might send signals at very similar carrier frequencies such that the receiver cannot select the required signal from the interfering one (co-channel interference); electrical machines, electric storms etc can produce electromagnetic waves over a whole range of frequencies which then degrade the received signal (noise).

Interference in the technical (scientific) sense, the overlap of waves of the same frequency resulting in regions where the waves add together to form a wave of larger amplitude (constructive interference) or smaller amplitude (destructive interference) can occur which can lead to the amplitude of the wave arriving at the receiver varying with time (fading).  One way that this can happen if for the transmitted wave travelling directly to a receiver but also being reflected from an object/region before arriving at the receiver.  The fact that that the is a path distance difference between the direct wave and the reflected wave can result a change in received signal amplitude.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So just to confirm, they don't affect each other if there are of different frequencies due to the superposition principle, like @SolomonSlow mentioned in his/her comment, right?

Comment: However, what would happen if two waves of different frequencies don't pass via one another, but travel together and reach the radio at the same time?

Comment: If the two signals arrive at the receiving antenna then they are overlapping but the receiver will amplify the signal whose frequency it is tuned to. If you have a smartphone then it will receive frequencies relating to the telephone companies signals, the WiFi router signals, the Bluetooth signal etc simultaneously. The phone will be set to deal with one, some or all of these signals simultaneously and the individual signals do not affect one another although they superpose.

Comment: I  see, thanks a lot!